# Headphone not working in Lubuntu 11.10 

Tags: sound, lubuntu, headphones

**The problem was not resolved, but I went back to 11.04**

*1. Description of the Problem*

The speaker works. When I plugin the headphone (tried 2 types), both the speaker and the headphone mute.

==============================================================

*2. I found this. How can I try this on Lubuntu?*

"All I needed to do was change the Profile on the Hardware tab of the Sound Setting screen from 'Analog Stereo Duplex' to 'Analog Stereo Output'." [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67143/upgraded-from-11-04-to-11-10-now-sound-isnt-working)

=============================================================

*3. Already tried*

(I) [[HP Pavilion dv6, IDT 92HD75B3] Line out does not mute internal speakers](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/871633)

Didn't work.

(II) [HdaIntelSoundHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto)

$ `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec`
`Codec: Conexant CX20549 (Venice)`

$ `sudo gnome-open /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz`
gives me a file, but for conexant, there're only `Conexant 5045`, `Conexant 5047`, `Conexant 5051`, `Conexant 5066`.

(III) [[Bug 876020] Re: [8932CTO, Conexant CX20549 (Venice), Green Headphone Out, Left] No sound at all](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg3258351.html)(Note: I needed rebooting.)

(i) Now when I plug in the headphone, the sound comes out of both the speaker and the headphone.

(ii) **automute** option in `alsamixer` is gone.

(iii) I cannot change the volume with `Fn+F10/F11` any more.

=============================================================

*4. More Info*

$ `sudo lshw -c sound`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

$ `sudo lshw -c sound`

```
*-multimedia            
   description: Audio device
   product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
   resources: irq:45 memory:f0300000-f0303fff
```

$ `sudo leafpad /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf`

```
; Path for mixers that have a 'Speaker' control
;
; See analog-output.conf.common for an explanation on the directives
[General]
priority = 100
name = analog-output-speaker

[Element Hardware Master]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right

[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right

[Element Master Front]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = front-left,front-right

[Element Master Mono]
switch = off
volume = off

; This profile path is intended to control the speaker, not the
; headphones. But it should not hurt if we leave the headphone jack
; enabled nonetheless.
[Element Headphone]
switch = mute
volume = zero

[Element Headphone2]
switch = mute
volume = zero

[Element Speaker]
required = any
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right

[Element Desktop Speaker]
switch = off
volume = off

[Element Front]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all-front
override-map.2 = front-left,front-right

[Element Rear]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all-rear
override-map.2 = rear-left,rear-right

[Element Surround]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all-rear
override-map.2 = rear-left,rear-right

[Element Side]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all-side
override-map.2 = side-left,side-right

[Element Center]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all-center
override-map.2 = all-center,all-center

[Element LFE]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = lfe
override-map.2 = lfe,lfe

.include analog-output.conf.common
```

Comment: Very well made question. I think you cover everything I could ask for. Is the computer you are using a Laptop HP DV6 just to be sure that the 3rd part is the same as your computer.

Comment: I went back to 11.04.

Comment: If you went back to 11.04 - then this question should be closed since we can no longer get feed back from you on trying stuff.

Comment: Closing this question as it seems you're no longer on 11.10 - if this isn't the case please flag the question for review stating the issue is still present.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi I experience the same issue on LUbuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work but it has for me before on different hardware. You could try to edit the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file adding at the end of the file the following

```
options snd-hda-intel position-fix=1
```

then, restart your machine and check if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't work.